# Parametric equations of a parabola with given axis, vertex and parameter

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, parametric

Write the parametric equations of the parabola with parameter $a = 3$,
vertex $(2, 5)$, axis r $2x + 3y = 19$ wholly contained in the half-plane $y\ge0$.

---

We have that $y = 3(x-2)^2 + 5$, so if we let $x=t$ then
\begin{align*} y &= 3(t-2)^2 + 5 \\  y &= 3t^2 -12t + 17 \end{align*}
So we have that the parametric coordinates are $(t, 3t^2 + 12t + 17)$.

Also, note that the angle between the line $2x + 3y = 19$ and the x-axis is $\theta = \tan^{-1}(\frac{-2}{3}) = -33.69^{\circ}$

Now if I rotate my parabola I end up with something like the following [image]

So now we have 2 triangles such that $a = t\cos\theta$ and $b=t\sin\theta$.
We also have that $c = 3t^2\sin\theta -12t\sin]theta + 17\sin\theta$ and $d = 3t^2\cos\theta -12t\cos\theta + 17\cos\theta$.

So now we have that 
$$y = t\sin\theta + 3t^2\cos\theta -12t\cos\theta + 17\cos\theta$$
and
$$x = t\cos\theta -3t^2\sin\theta + 12t\sin\theta-17\sin\theta$$

Multiplying $x$ by $\cos$ and $y$ by $\sin$ and adding them together gives us $$x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta = t\cos^2\theta+t\sin^2\theta$$
$$\implies x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta = t$$

Substituting $t$ in we get
\begin{align*}
y(1-sin^2\theta) - x\cos\theta\sin\theta &= 3(x\cos\theta+t\sin\theta)^2\cos\theta -12(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)\cos\theta+17\cos\theta  \\
y\cos\theta - x\sin\theta &= 3(x\cos\theta+t\sin\theta)^2-12(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)+17
\end{align*}

---

Is what I have done above correct or have is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You’re certainly doing a lot more work than necessary. For one thing, you don’t need to know the rotation angle explicitly since you really only want its sine and cosine, which you can derive from the slope of the axis. However, it would be even easier to you start off with the vertex at the origin and then rotate and translate, which is what Narasimnham does in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2469357/265466).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Please check this combination of rotation and translation:

$$ x_1= 2 a t,   y_1= at^2$$
$$ x= x_1 \cos \theta - y_1 \sin \theta +2,\, $$
$$y= x_1 \sin \theta - y_1 \cos \theta +5 . $$

Comment: Thanks. Indicated a way to proceed so OP could check it. I did not check it myself.